# Installation problem in making partitions

Tags: partitioning

while installing Ubuntu in windows 10 which is partitioned as separate drives  by me,i couldn't find the free space in "something Else "option..It shows entire drive for making partitions..and i want to install it in a particular drive.what can i do  ?

Comment: Do not mix drives (physical devices) with partitions. And Windows may use drive for either. You cannot create partitions with Windows for Linux use. Just leave space unallocated. And make sure Windows fast start up or always on hibernation is off. Is Windows installed in UEFI or BIOS boot mode. You need to install Ubuntu in same boot mode. And how you boot installer UEFI or BIOS is then how it install.